# Magento 2.4 404 error category pages

Tags: magento2

I installed magento 2.4 on a testserver where i can not change the root folder to pub. I changed the .htaccess in the root to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I can see the site logo and menu, but the content part gives a 404

When i add pub/ to the url everything is showing.

How to changed the .htaccess so that adding /pub is not nesseccary

Comment: If possible, its better to set the document root of the host to the /pub folder. Do you already set 
`'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
]`
in env.php? See [the docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html).

Comment: Run a2enmod rewrite
followed by service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update below code in Magento root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: No difference, stil need to add the pub like this http://185.56.144.149/~jilco/pub/tricot-kinderstoffen.html